# Spring Boot Devtools issue on SpringBoot 2.0.0.M4

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to run a Spring boot app using below versions:

```
<version>2.0.0.M4</version>
<java.version>1.9</java.version>
<spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

My application works as expected but when I add the below dependency (spring-boot-devtools), I'm getting an error when I try to run:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader

I have tried to run with old version as below and it works fine.

```
<version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<java.version>1.9</java.version>
<spring.version>5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>
```

I was wondering if someone can point us if I'm doing something wrong here, or do we have an issue with 2.0.0.M4?

Thanks

Singh

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10454. Use the snapshot version for Spring Boot (don't use the snapshot for Spring).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when I was using jdk 11 with my spring boot app. You have to use an older version of the jdk like version 8 and if that does not work then you upgrade your spring boot version. The former worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a spring boot dev-tool incompatibility with java version 9.
I met this problem using stable version of spring boot.

Comment: According to : http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/talks/prepare-for-jdk9-j1-2015.pdf

Java 9 not uses `java.net.URLClassLoader ` any more.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in Spring Boot `<version>2.0.0.M7</version>`
with java 9

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I had resolved it by reducing the version of JDK to 1.8. however, I am using a lower version of springboot but you can upgrade your JDK version in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests there is an incompatible JDK, this could be due to multiple JDK on your classpath, and when dev-tool is trying to run the application, it ends up picking the wrong JDK.